# Save text from 2D JTextField array using BufferedWriter & Loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, bufferedwriter

I have a 2D array called `fields` and I need to be able to save its contents (colour initials).

```
try {
    BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Drawing_NEW.csv"));
    for (int y = 0; y < totalY; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < totalX - 1; x++) {
            outFile.write(fields[x][y].getText() + ",");
        }
        outFile.write(fields[totalX - 1][y].getText());
        outFile.newLine();
    }
    outFile.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

The code above saves everything in the array like this. Note the array is 20 by 20 (The output below is just a snippet of the whole thing).

```
W,W,W,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,W,W
W,W,W,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,W,W
```

But I have to now make a loop where if the colour is the same as the next add one to the counter and if it does not then write the new colour and set the counter back to 1 then check again for the next and so on. below are a sample template and output of what it's supposed to look like.

```
(colour1,count1, colour2,count2, colour3,count3,)

W,3,G,15,W,2
W,3,G,3,Y,5,G,7,W,2
```

Feel free to ask questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you need to add some state to your loops to track previous values. AFAIU from your example, you want to write a number only for the sequence of the same string in the same "line" of the array. If this is so, try following code

```
for (int y = 0; y < totalY; y++) {
    string prev = ""; // this value doesn't equal anything you can see in the UI, so the first iteration of the loop works as expected 
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < totalX - 1; x++) {
        string cur = fields[x][y].getText();
        if(cur.equals(prev)) {
            cnt ++;
        }
        else {
            if(cnt > 0) // skip the first empty line
              outFile.write(prev + "," + cnt + ",");
            prev = cur;
            cnt = 1;
        }
    }
    // write the last sequence
    outFile.write(prev + "," + cnt);
    outFile.newLine();
}
```

Comment: Close but some initials are in the wrong place the proper output should be `W,3,G,15,W,2` but it gives me `G,3,W,15,W,2`. Here's a link to the [code](https://pastebin.com/A5hqmkVN)

Comment: @Nicz, please try updated code, I used `cur` instead of `prev` in `outFile.write`